# How to disabled Phusion Passenger for hosting on Plesk? When I refresh web app in VueJS I always have error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, passenger, plesk

My server has Plesk and I have mydomain.com with frontend in Vue and backend in api.mydomain.com with laravel. Before, when I went to mydomain.com/clients and tried to refresh the page, I got an error with Phusion Passenger. I have disabled Phusion Passenger on this domain but I don't remember how I did it.

Now, I have the same problem with the same front and back system. The only difference is that both domains are subdomains, that is, I have front.domain.es and api.domain.es.

If I refresh front.domain.com it works perfectly. If I navigate from the system menu it works fine. But, if I am in front.domain.com/clients for example and I try to refresh page, I get Pushion Passenger error.

Important comment that the system work perfectly, just when you try to refresh the page has this error. On the first example that I comment, now works perfecty without Passenger, I can refresh without problem, but I don't remember how I did it.

I want to disable Phusion Passenger for this hosting on plesk or domain or whatever, I hope you can help me!

Thank you very much!!

Log File:
[ E 2023-02-02 08:44:42.0486 476333/Tf age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/front.domain.com: The application process exited prematurely.
Error ID: dbcc318c
Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-BX09me.html

Answer (score 0):

Go in Tools&Settings >> PHP Setting

In top of the page you should find this " Select the PHP handlers you want to make available. You can install additional handlers using the Plesk Installer. "

Follow the link and will take you to Plesk Installer, there you can enable/disable modules including fusion

Comment: HI Vasile Alecu!! Thank you for your answer.
Sorry, but I can't apply your solution because, if I do that, NodeJs will be deleted without option to install alone.